# How to present navigation controller with tab bar controller

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have navigation controller and tab bar controller. TBC is embeded in NC. When I present VC from another VC, I see only NC and not TBC there. I want them both to be presented. What should I do?

Here is my code:

```
let mainAreaVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainAreaVC") as! MainAreaVC
let mainAreaVCe = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainAreaVC)
self.present(mainAreaVCe, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image]

Comment: is MainAreaVC is tabbarController ?

Comment: @Ajaysaini No, VC stands for view controller and its view controller storyboard id. I think someone got me an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show `MainAreaVC` with both `NavigationController` and `TabBarcontroller` then you need to present the `UITabBarController` instead of `MainAreaVC`. So in storyboard set the `Storyboard Id` for your `TabBarController` something like `TabbarVC` or what ever you want then use it wit `instantiateViewController` to get `UITabBarController`.

```
let tabbarVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabbarVC") as! UITabBarController
self.present(tabbarVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried that way but my mistake was writing 'MainAreaVC' (class file) instead of 'UITabBarController'. Now I get it how it works.

Comment: @Ts.Gams Welcome mate :)